# How to concatenate number arrays with "±" string?

Tags: string, matlab

I have two arrays, results and errors:

```
Results = [ 1.0 2.2 3.5 ];
Erorrs  = [ 0.2 0.2 0.3 ];
```

And I need a new text array variable  (maybe cell) that will look schematically like:

```
[Results(i),'$^\pm$', Erorrs(i)]
```

(with 3 lines in the example)

Comment: Please consider accepting one of the answers to indicate that your problem is solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Use `sprintf` and the unicode char ± with `char(177)`

```
for ii = 1:numel(Erorrs)
   s{ii} = sprintf('%f %c %f', Results(ii), char(177), Erorrs(ii))
end
```

I think the Latex-Interpreter does not work here, though I am not sure about that.

---

```
s =

  1×3 cell array

    {'1.000000 ± 0.200000'}    {'2.200000 ± 0.200000'}    {'3.500000 ± 0.300000'}
```

Alternatively use `fprintf` with `\r\n` for console output.

---

Thanks to the comment of @matlabbit, there is also a vectorized version:

```
compose('%f %c %f', Results(:), char(177), Erorrs(:))
```

Comment: it kind of works! thank you

Comment: kind of? what does not work? do you actually want to print the `\pm`?

Comment: yes, is it possible?

Comment: @MichaelL. it was actually easier than I thought, have a look at my edit

Comment: You can vectorize sprintf by using compose instead. compose("%f ± %f", Results', Erorrs')

Comment: @matlabbit thanks! I wasn't aware of that function.

Answer (score 5):

Using a [string](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/string.html) array, it can be done like this:

```
s = string(Results) + char(177) + string(Erorrs);
```

```
>> s
s = 
  1×3 string array
    "1±0.2"    "2.2±0.2"    "3.5±0.3"
```

Comment: s = Results + "±" + Erorrs; would be the same exact behavior and save on some typing.

Comment: @matlabbit I would recommend against it. That saved in an m file on a platform that uses ANSI or other similar unsupportive encodings will mess it up.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `strcat`

```
E = strsplit(num2str(Erorrs))
R = strsplit(num2str(Results))
p = cell(1,3);
p(:) = "$^\pm$";
s = strcat(R,p,E);
```

such that

```
s =
{
  [1,1] = 1$^pm$0.2
  [1,2] = 2.2$^pm$0.2
  [1,3] = 3.5$^pm$0.3
}
```